# Accessing P&T Assets files from WYGWAM

Tags: assets, wygwam

I just uploaded P&T Assets. Shouldn't I be able to access my Assets directories from a WYGWAM? I don't have any folder listed in the WYGWAM settings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go into Add-Ons -> Fieldtypes and click on Settings next to your WYGWAM fieldtype. In there, click on the Settings button. There's a setting called "File Browser". Choose Assets instead of the EE File Manager. Click Submit.

Now, when you're in a WYGWAM field, click on the image icon like usual to add an image, then click "Browse Server". This will bring up the Assets panel.